# Link to files form another solution

Tags: file, model-view-controller, path, project, solution

I want to show a image what is saved in another solution in the same project. 
Solution TouchUI have a folder called images.
In Solution WebUI I want to load a image from the folder. How can I do that?

```
<img src="../WebUI/Images/movieimages/@item.MoviePicture" alt="@item.MovieName" class="img-thumbnail">
```

gives me a 404. Anybody an idea?

Answer (score 0):

I copied the files to the new solution in stead of linking to another solution.